# How to manipulate this matrix?

Tags: r

I have 3 columns with a lot of rows. The 1st and 3th column are names & the 2nd column are values. I would like to create a new matrix/data.frame where the 1st column of the original matrix becomes unique rownames, the 3th column becomes unique columnnames and the values from the 2nd column are correctly filled in the new matrix.

[Original Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egk7n.png)

Comment: Try `xtabs(abundance ~ sample_id + taxon_id, df1)`

Comment: Getting this error
`xtabs(abundance ~ sample_id + taxon_id,a)`
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Comment: Looks like `abundance` is not a numeric column.  Check your dataset.  If it is not, then convert it to numeric

Comment: @akrun Yeah, just found it, but still getting kind of the same table.  
https://imgur.com/a/K99tjfA

Comment: `xtabs` should normally work.  For eg. `xtabs(mpg ~ am + gear, mtcars)`  You havfen't provided any repro example with `dput`.  So, it is not able to check the issue

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to agregate some rows, because if you have a combinaison of unique `sample_id` and unique `taxon_id` that repeats twice, you can't have a unique rowname and a unique colname in the final output.
I made the hypothesis to sum the values of a unique sample-taxon combinaison (with the function `group_by()` and `summarise()` of the library **dplyr**).

Then, as I'm sure to have unique sample-taxon combinaisons, I used the function `spread()` from the library **tidyr** in order to transform the colum `taxon-id` as columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(
  sample_id = rep('SRX14', 4),
  abundance = c(5, 0, 645, 1042),
  taxon_id  = c('TACGG', 'AACGT', 'TACGG', 'TACGA')
) %>% 

  group_by(sample_id, taxon_id) %>% 
  summarise(abundance = sum(abundance)) %>% 

  spread(key = taxon_id, value = abundance)

#   sample_id AACGT TACGA TACGG
#   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 SRX14         0  1042   650
```